# WooCommerce - list cart item names outside of the product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a simple bulleted list of items that have already been added to the cart, which will later be passed through a gravity form field. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
<?php global $woocommerce; 

      $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

      foreach($items as $item => $product_id) { ?>

            <li><?php echo $item; ?></li>

      <?php } ?>
```

I have 2 items added to the cart, and get a result of:

- 747579165776fe1ba349237464ae0eed
- f06a642b52d91adfa0168b737bd60db9

However, I am trying to grab the title of the products rather than the key.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to do this way:

```
<?php global $woocommerce; 

  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
  foreach($items as $item => $values) { ?>
        <? // print_r($item); ?>
        <? $_product = $values['data']->post; ?>
        <? echo $_product->post_title; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

You can access then to any post value, post_title, post_date, ID, etc.
Uncomment the // print_r($item); and see what i mean.
Also you can play with other data changing a bit the part with: $_product = $values['data']->post;
For example to access the product ID, not the post ID, change the inside of foreach function to this:

```
$_product = $values['data'];
echo $_product->ID;
```

Print $_product to see the rest of values available.

In fact, always do a print_r to see what´s inside an array.

That´s it.

Comment: When I echo `$_product->ID` this it shows all products ID's, how can I get last of them, for example here are returned values `1297,1694,1297,3911,4999,` how to get only 4999?